# Linq Query Not Returning Value

Tags: c#, linq

- Framework: .Net 4.5

I'm working on populating textbox fields with data from my DB. However, after debugging I've found that my Linq queries are not returning a value.

```
protected void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    API_DatabaseEntities1 db = new API_DatabaseEntities1();

    if (ddlCustomer.SelectedValue == "Marisol") {

        tbDescription.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                                where c.CustomerID == 4
                                select c.ProductDescription).ToString();
        tbFName.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                        where c.CustomerID == 4
                        select c.Fname).ToString();
        tbSocial.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                            where c.CustomerID == 4
                            select c.SSN).ToString();
        tbDOB.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                        where c.CustomerID == 4
                        select c.DOB).ToString();
        tbFName1.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                            where c.CustomerID == 4
                            select c.Fname).ToString();
        tbMName.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                        where c.CustomerID == 4
                        select c.Mname).ToString();
        tbLName.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                        where c.CustomerID == 4
                        select c.Lname).ToString();
        tbPrimaryPhone.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                                where c.CustomerID == 4
                                select c.PrimaryPhone).ToString();
        tbSecondaryPhone.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                                    where c.CustomerID == 4
                                    select c.SecondaryPhone).ToString();
        tbAdd1.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                        where c.CustomerID == 4
                        select c.Address).ToString();
        tbCity.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                        where c.CustomerID == 4
                        select c.City).ToString();
        tbZip.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                        where c.CustomerID == 4
                        select c.Zip).ToString();
        tbEmail.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                        where c.CustomerID == 4
                        select c.Email).ToString();
        tbMonLease.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                            where c.CustomerID == 4
                            select c.MortLeaseAmt).ToString();
        tbEmployer.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                            where c.CustomerID == 4
                            select c.Employer).ToString();
        tbPosition.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                            where c.CustomerID == 4
                            select c.Position).ToString();
        tbHireDate.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                            where c.CustomerID == 4
                            select c.Position).ToString();
        tbWorkPhone.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                            where c.CustomerID == 4
                            select c.WorkPhone).ToString();
        tbGross.Text = (from c in db.Customers
                        where c.CustomerID == 4
                        select c.GrossIncome).ToString();

    }

    Debug.WriteLine(tbGross.Text);
}
```

At this point I'm not sure if there is an issue with my DB connection or with my Linq Query. I appreciate any help you might be able to offer.

Comment: "not returning value" *which one*?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to get all the Customer properties with a single query? rather than using a new query each time you want to get a property?

Comment: @Ian At this point, none of them are returning a value.

Comment: FYI: you are pounding your database with a bunch of separate queries to pull individual values off the same record.  You should make one query to get all values.

Comment: @Mowrite could that be your query failed in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant get one customer and not a list.

`select` will return you a collection and not one item, change it like this:

```
  var customer = (from c in db.Customers
                 where c.CustomerID == 4
                 select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note the call of `FirstOrDefault()`, this will return 1 customer instead of a list that contains 1 customer.

`FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` if nothing was returned by the query:

```
 if(customer == null)
     return; // no customer found
```

You can then populate your text fields like this:

```
   tbDescription.Text = customer.ProductDescription;
   tbFName.Text = customer.Fname;

   etc.
```

Comment: You should also check to make sure customer is not null before trying to read the values

Comment: @snow_FFFFFF indeed, fixed thanks

Comment: @thumbmunkeys Thank you! Right now it appears that the customer object is not returning, null. However, when I equate DB values to my textbox ID's, the values remain empty. When running "customer" through debug, it returns a lengthy numerical value, rather than query results. Thoughts?

Comment: hmm, hard to say without more information, but you're sure there is a customer with `CustomerId == 4`?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys not a problem. Certainly understand that. I did double check that just to make sure, and yes, there is a CustomerID == 4. Each of my textbox variables correlate directly to the proper TB ID, so I'm not entirely sure why these field are returning blank. Perhaps, I'll try it with a different CustomerID to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I did verify that. Perhaps I'm missing something on the front end? Example of front end code: First Name:<asp:TextBox ID="tbFName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

Comment: sorry, don't know a thing about ASP :)

Answer (score 0):

Please do this:

```
var oneRec = (from c in db.Customer
                  where c.CustomerID == 4
                  select c).FirstOrDefault();

tbDescription.Text = oneRec.ProductDescription;
tbFName.Text = oneRec.Fname;
tbSocial.Text = oneRec.SSN;

// ect
```